# Installing google assistant library on non-GMS android build

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

running commands through termux on android phone from google assistant tutorial, giving following error :

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-assistant-library (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for google-assistant-library

Comment: You're trying to install a python library on your Android phone? Which phone?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/install-sample                                                                                        The library is only supported on devices with linux-armv7l and linux-x86_64 architectures                                                                         I am trying on nexus whose hardware configuration is : Linux localhost 3.10.73-g33ace82f84b #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 13 04:41:33 UTC 2017 aarch64 Android

Comment: It may be trying to find an aarch64 version of the library, which is not a supported configuration, even though the code may actually run in that configuration (since it seems to be arm-like)